# Elements disappear on mobile sizes

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

Website is not customized to mobile devices (no responsive). I don't know why on small screens some element disappear. I mean two footer sections - you can see on screen.

[image]

It is footer section.

Comment: Since we are not necessarily on a mobile device right now, can you instead write out here the HTML and CSS of the sections that disappear so we can get a better idea of why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your style.css, from lines 2945 to 2948 you have this :

```
@media (max-width: 643px) {


    ul.nav-menu, div.nav-menu > ul {
        display: none;
    }


}
```

So when the width of the screen is below 643px, the element is not show. You can just remove theses lines

Comment: You are right. It was in child theme. Thx for help.